# Calls to defunct tkinter (python GUI) widgets are hanging

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I'm dialing up a GUI using tkinter, and I am trying to be a responsible citizen by cleaning up all of my threads when my application is closed.  My application is multi-threaded, with a polling engine regularly sending updates back to my display.  I'm using resource locking to control access to shared resources, (NOT shown in the example code, below).  The problem is that quite frequently after closing the application window I am stuck with leftover threads.

I've tried to show what I'm working with in the code below: The callbacks to "update" are asynchronous. The problem is that between the time that I check "self._active" for the status of the underlying widgets and the time that I make the calls to "...frameWidget.configure(style=..." and "...varToUpdate.set(...", the state of those widgets may have been altered by the tkinter engine to some flavor of 'defunct'/'unresponsive'.

Using a Lock does not help.  I have not found a way to control the state of the widgets to keep them from 'dying' until I can clean things up.  The event notifications appear to be simply that: they tell you that an event has occurred, but they do not allow you to delay widget-'death' until you can finish cleaning up.

The real problem appears to be that the calls to configure the style of the widget ("self.frameWidget.configure(style = stylename)") and to update the IntVar ("self.varToUpdate.set(value)") simply hang/block when the GUI has been shut down.
Rather than producing an exception, or just yielding nothing, those method calls never return.  (This does not seem like good behavior to me.)

So.  How to deal with this?   Any ideas?  I would really LOVE the ability to specify a chunk of code as "atomic" somehow so that I could guarantee that the object manipulation was guaranteed to be run immediately after the check for "._active" but I have not seen anything like that in Python.  Even if I could achieve that, I am not sure how the tkinker engine actually goes about updating the objects, so that might not solve the problem.  Am I missing something?

And yes, I'm new to python, bla bla bla...  I come from a Java background, so I assume that much of what I have written is decidedly "un-pythonic".  I am quite happy to hear your insight on how I might improve things here to leverage the strengths of the language.

The example code!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from myutil import Subscriber

threshold = 20
deactivationEvents = ("Deactivate", "Destroy", "Unmap")
activationEvents = ("Activate", "Map")

# class implements/inherits "listener pattern" functionality
class MyClass(Subscriber)
  def __init__(self, parentWidget):
    self._active = False
    self.frame = ttk.LabelFrame(parentWidget, text='something')
    self.varToUpdate = IntVar()
    self.bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.frame, orient=VERTICAL)
    self.bar.config(mode='determinate', maximum=100, variable=self.varToUpdate)
    self.moreThings()
    self.bindWidgetEvents():

  . more
  . code
  . here

  # I'm using a simple boolean flag to control access here
  # I've tried using threading.Lock as well, to no avail
  def update(self, value):
    stylename = "{}.TFrame".format("Normal" if value > threshold else "Alarm")
    if self._active:
      self.frame.configure(style=stylename)
      self.varToUpdate.set(value)

  def bindWidgetEvents(self):
    widgets = [self.bar, self.frame]
    self.bindActivationEvents(widgets)
    self.bindDeactivationEvents(widgets)

  def bindActivationEvents(self, widgets):
    def activate(event):
      self._active = True
    for widget in widgets:
      for event in activationEvents:
        widget.bind("<{}>".format(event), activate)

  def bindDeactivationEvents(self, widgets):
    def deactivate(event):
      self._active = False
    for widget in widgets:
      for event in deactivationEvents:
        widget.bind("<{}>".format(event), deactivate)
```

Comment: Just make the threads daemons so they die with the parent thread.

Comment: Well, that certainly worked!  I still feel like those methods should raise an exception rather than hanging the way that they do... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background threads as daemons worked just fine

```
t = Thread(target=self.pollData)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Thread 't' ends when the main thread exits

I still feel that the tkinter methods behave poorly by blocking/hanging rather than raising an exception in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

While assigning the threads as daemons works in this particular case, that doesn't really help unless we are actually closing the application.  What if I were merely closing a window, or a frame?  Then we're stuck with the problem of the methods of these defunct GUI items being called and hanging the thread...

We need a way to keep those methods from being called, but we cannot depend on a check-then-call solution because these are not atomic operations.

Here's another idea...  What do people think about this as a solution?

```
  # The tkinter GUI objects were hanging indefinitely upon calls to their methods after
  # the window was closed, so we will replace them with dummy objects that will recieve 
  # those calls instead
  def deactivate(self):
    self._active = False
    self.varToUpdate = Stub()  # we could probably just reinitialize an IntVar
    self.bar = Stub()
    self.frame = Stub()

class Stub(object):

  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def config(self, **kwargs):
    pass

  def set(self, value):
    pass
```

We might also simply delete the objects and add handling to catch the resulting exceptions when calls are made to the now non-existant objects...

```
  def deactivate(self):
    self._active = False
    del self.varToUpdate
    del self.bar
    del self.frame
```

Unfortunately, even with these solutions, I think there is still a chance that the shutdown of the objects could occur after the calls to the GUI objects have been made.